# Rearranging string with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Having the following string:

```
>db|version.x|name of entry 1
properties of entry1
>db|version.x|name of entry 2
properties of entry2
```

In the lines starting with ">", I would like to move the number to the front, separated by a space from the rest of the old text, leaving properties of the entry intact, so that it looks like this:

```
>1 db|version.x|name of entry 1
properties of entry1
>2 db|version.x|name of entry 2
properties of entry
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/^>/, ">"$NF" ")}1' File

>1 db|version.x|name of entry 1
properties of entry1
>2 db|version.x|name of entry 2
properties of entry2
```